# Paperclip not showing image even though URL/images in correct places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

Using Paperclip to attach avatars to User profiles for my rails application. I followed the instructions on the paperclip github to initialize and attach to my app.

I have an image in the public/images/medium/missing.png and for both cases (when I upload or when I fallback on the default) I get no image. I've checked my directory and there is an image where it says it is looking but does not grab it. Additionally when I have tried uploading images, I know the image is uploaded correctly because when calling the User in rails console shows all the information properly attached.

I am calling the image in my view like:

```
<%= image_tag(@blog.user.avatar.url(":medium"), :class => "image-circle avatar") %>
```

my Paperclip declaration in the User model looks like the following:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#"}, :default_url => "/public/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Really not sure what is going on. The route errors that appear when I inspect the improperly loaded image point directly to the image in my local server. And the fact that it can't grab either the missing or the uploaded file also has me at a loss. Any help would be super appreciated!!

And for good measure the output when I examine a user with an uploaded avatar:

```
avatar_file_name: "11390219_10206114805925816_6595348111261743639_n.j...", avatar_content_type: "image/jpeg", avatar_file_size: 101926, avatar_updated_at: "2015-07-10 18:51:44">
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

This is the URL that is providing the 404 error:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/medium/missing.png
```

while in my local directory it goes "root/public/images/medium/missing.png"

not sure how its not grabbing it, unless I am just missing something really obvious somewhere. (i tried hard routing the public in there as well, but to no avail).

Comment: What's the url the image helper generates? You can paste the url right into the browser and see what type of error you are getting. Is the error 404? If that's the case, then you have an invalid URL.

Comment: When I copy the url is says there is no such route, but when inspecting the element it is a 404 error.. not sure how i should go about fixing the URL then.

Comment: Still stuck on this, even just trying to have it grab the "missing" will not work on the local host. I have the image in public/images/medium/missing.png and the route as dictated above and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

There is the possibility that you're simply not serving the static assets, add:

```ruby
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

to your development.rb

ORIGINAL POST

In you application.rb ( or an environment specific file ), you should have a config.paperclip_defaults = { ... }, here is the link in the docs: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults

Here is an example one, using fog:

```ruby
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
    :provider => "Local",
    :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"
  },
  :fog_directory => "",
  :fog_host => "localhost:3000"
}
```

Do you have something like that in your application? I just tested on an app of mine, and I was able to upload an image, but not to see any without the paperclip_defaults hash. Also, don't forget to restart your app after you update the config files. I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried out the example default and it didn't work, I'll try to mess with the options and such. But I understood overriding the defaults as being more for cases where you need to store images on a separate service and so not have to specify the storage for every has_attachment attribute. Unless that dictates where it should be looking? As I have been generating urls that line up with where the images are on my local server, but i can't even access the public folder if i type in the url directly. Thank you for the suggestions tho! I'll look more into the defaults.

Comment: Perhaps this is overly obvious, but do you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your development.rb?

Comment: Jesus that was it, I had looked at that file at least 50 times and just didn't register it. Thank you so much!!!! Sometimes the most obvious things..

Comment: Also, you may need to specify the :path option; I don't know what type of storage you're using, but this part of the docs might be helpful [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) That could explain the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried killing the quotes around the image style? Around :medium?

```ruby
<%= image_tag(@blog.user.avatar.url(:medium), :class => "image-circle avatar") %>
```

As show here in the Paperclip Docs:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view

Comment: Oops! Didn't realize I posted it that way. Yea I was just trying various things, I have tried it without the quotes and still no luck.

Comment: Try not including "/public" in the :default_url... that will be a start for getting the default image in there. Also, can you post your config.paperclip_defaults = { ... }?

Comment: Just tried and still no luck, the thing insists on not being found. As for the default hash, I haven't modified it. But now that I look can't seem to find it. Should it have appeared somewhere during installation if I haven't changed it?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, solved it by reinstalling imagemagic with brew

Details: In case you're imagemagic, try to update the imagemagic and if it asks you to link it, 
Try with this:

```
 brew link --overwrite imagemagick
```

It worked for me. Hope its helpful